# After launching npx create-react-app in the terminal I get this error in the terminal

Tags: reactjs

I'm running OSX and all I did was initialize create-react-app and tried to run it using 'npm start' i'm not sure what the error is.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
Error: [BABEL] /Users/cloud/Desktop/js/projects/OfficialProjects/pomodoro/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js: Cannot find module './src/data' (While processing: "/Users/cloud/Desktop/js/projects/OfficialProjects/pomodoro/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/dependencies.js$0$9")
```

Answer (score 1):

delete node_modules folder and re-run yarn install or npm install

Comment: I tried doing that, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's been a bad build of npm package `core-js-compat`. This is a deep-down dependency of Babel. Lots of things will be affected, things that use Babel. It's not specifically to do with create-react-app -- you were just unfortunate to update your npm package versions while a bad build was live.

You will experience the problem if you have core-js-compat v.3.4.6. You can check this by doing `npm list core-js-compat`. The problem is apparently fixed by v.3.4.7, which was pushed out pretty quickly, about half-an-hour later, but unfortunately it takes a while to spread out through the repositories. You can either wait until an `npm update` gets you v.3.4.7 or you can go manually download v.3.4.7 if you want to get going right away.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/710). It seems to be a problem with another package